# How can I use JSON to link my html form to update a sharepoint list?

Tags: json, sharepoint

At the moment I'm just trying to add name to the list. I'll add more when I get that working.

I'm currently getting errors in the debugger with the following :

```
var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
```

Also, I've more than one column in the list, could that be it?

What I have:

```
$('#submitdata').click(function () {
        //this gets the value from your name input
        var name = $('#name').val();

var data = {
        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.ProjectsListItem' },
       "name": name,

  };
$.ajax({
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    $.ajax({
               url: siteurl + "/mysite/Lists/getbytitle('ChangeOfAddressList')/items",
               method: "POST",
                             data: JSON.stringify(data),
               headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                               "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()                                  
               },
               success: function (data) {
                          alert('Item added successfully');
              },
              error: function (error) {
                  alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
             }
      });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
 <form id="COA_Form" name="myForm" method="post" action="" >
  <input type='text' id='name' />
  <input type='submit' id='submitdata' value='submit' />
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I use the [Shockout framework](https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms) to set up forms in SharePoint.  The code base may offer some insight into what you are trying to solve.  I would look at line 2752 or 3142 of the [js file](https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms/blob/master/JavaScript/ShockoutForms-1.0.6.js) and trace back from there.  Or just use the Shockout framework.

Answer (score 0):

To test your code, change the line

`var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;`

to

`var siteurl = 'https://spsitedomain';`.

Of course you would want to use your actual SharePoint site domain instead of 'spsitedomain'.

You can open the console and see what the `_spPageContextInfo` object yields.  In my browser, I either get `undefined` or I get an object that does not have a `webAbsoluteUrl` property (depending on the page I am viewing), so your mileage may vary when using this object.